# Updating pandas series based on updating website BS4

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have made a script that scrapes a population website. The website constantly updates as new population information comes in. I can scrape it at a given time, and it will return what that instant of the data is. I have also created a function that will convert the data to a pandas series. However, I would like to make this a continuous scraping, and change the pandas series that I am using as the website updates.

Where can I find out how to do this?

website:https://countrymeters.info/en/Japan

As it is a population clock, it naturally will update. I would like to be able to update my series in response to such changes.

Basically, when I pass something like:

```
s = Scraper().getSeries()
```

I get a series of the scraped data. Scraper is a class that converts the table data into a series. Again, it is only a temporary version of the site; the site soon updates after.

Comment: The website does not have a feed, so I guess you would have to do refreshes manually at a small interval. You could use a while loop that runs indefinitely. Within this loop you apply your Scraper().getSeries()

Comment: I have thought about doing something like that with time.sleep, however won't that cause the program itself to lag?

Comment: Well, if you use 500ms delay, i.e. half a second, I guess there is very little delay in your script. I don't know what you want to do exactly after running your data, but keeping everything in the while loop should keep it running until you brute force stop your code.